# nontype object has no function python3

Tags: python

I wrote a program is python3 but I don't understand why when I call the function printed it returns the right output but when I call the same function in "find()" I have a no type object. In particular I have the error at the fourth line of the function "find()" when I use keys on the variable data. Can you help me understanding what's going on? Thanks

```
def printed(filename, day, time):
try:
    f = open(filename)
    lines = f.readlines()
    d = defaultdict(list)
    start = lines.index(day+"\n")
    if day == 'Monday\n' or day == 'Tuesday\n' or day == 'Wednesday\n' or day == 'Thursday\n' or day == 'Friday\n':
        stop = lines.index("Saturday\n")
    elif day == 'Saturday\n':
        stop = lines.index("Sunday\n")
    else:
        stop = len(lines)
    hour = time[0] + time[1]
    minutes = time[3:]
    for line in lines[start:stop]:
        line = line.strip(",")
        line = line.replace("\n","")
        line = line.replace(" ","")
        line = line.split(".")
        key = line[0]
        if len(line) == 2:
            d[key] += [line[1]]
    d = dict(d)
    print(d)
except IOError:
    print("File not found")
    program()
```

...

```
def find(filename, day, time):
    try:
        data = printed(filename, day, time)
        data2 = [int(h) * 60 + int(m) for h in data.keys() for m in data[h]]
        start_hour, start_minute = map(int, time.split('.'))
        start = start_hour * 60 + start_minute
        end = start + 30
        after = list(filter(lambda x: start <= x <= end, data2))
        if len(after) == 0:
            return "\nThere is no bus for this time"
        return list(map(lambda x: '%02d.%02d' % (x // 60, x % 60), after))
    except IOError:
        print("The file was not found")
        program()
```

Here is the output of printed():

```
'12': ['06', '36', '06', '36'], '13': ['06', '36', '06', '36'], 
'11': ['06', '36', '06', '36'], '21': ['05', '35', '06', '35'], 
'18': ['11', '26', '41', '56', '06', '36'], '06': ['11', '26', '41', '56', '35'], 
'15': ['06', '36', '56', '06', '36'], '19': ['11', '40', '06', '35'], 
'17': ['11', '26', '41', '56', '06', '36'], '22': ['05', '35', '06', '35'], 
'07': ['11', '26', '41', '56', '05', '35'], '09': ['06', '36', '06', '36'], 
'20': ['05', '35', '06', '35'], '14': ['06', '36', '06', '36'], 
'10': ['06', '36', '06', '36'], '16': ['11', '26', '41', '56', '06', '36'], 
'23': ['05', '35', '06', '35'], '08': ['11', '26', '41', '06', '36']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuz you put a print at the end of the printed() function. To call it you have to put a return instead of a print. Change:

```
print(d)
```

with:

```
return d
```